# angular JS endlesslist and search functionality?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS i have an object of which contains nearly 4000 records which i am showing them using ng-repeat

```
<div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
<li ng-repeat="outlet in outlets  | filter:searchText" >
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
            <div clss="title">{{outlet.name}}</div>
            <div class="discription">{{outlet.address}},{{outlet.cityName}},{{outlet.countyName}}</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</li>
</div>
```

now i wanted to use endless list by using [ng-infinitescroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) but the problem is the filter is happening only which are visible not in total 4000 records so what do i have to implement to get the search functionality to be done in total 4000 records and endless list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searchText filter would only work on in-memory data. In order to search things that havent been loaded yet you would need to implement a server-side search api.

Comment: Thanks i got an idea like implementing the search filter query